# ASP.Core bind to byte[] doesn't work

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I am sending this query to an ASP.Core controller action (*I added the line breaks for readability*):

```
GET http://localhost:5000/Files/AddFileConfirmed?generatedId=90
                                                &generatedId=73
                                                &generatedId=25
                                                &generatedId=199
                                                &generatedId=69
                                                &generatedId=245
                                                &generatedId=238
                                                &generatedId=83
                                                &generatedId=164
                                                &generatedId=208
                                                &generatedId=156
                                                &generatedId=83
```

If the action accepts `int[]` then the `generatedId` is bond correctly but if it if `byte[]` it fails.  The array should be a byte array rather than an integer one.

```
[HttpGet]
public string AddFileConfirmed(int[] generatedId)
{
    return $"ID = {(generatedId == null? "Null" : String.Join(", ", generatedId))}";
}
```

Why can't I bind to a byte array?

Comment: There probably is not a default model binder that can handler byte arrays. Check that first. Good news is that the framework is flexible enough for you to create you own binder to handle it. You should also look into using proper parameter attributes that could help solve your problem.

Comment: Cheers @Nkosi, a binder lacking sounds probably.  What did you mean by _"proper parameter attributes"_ though?

Comment: In core as apposed to previous versions you have to explicitly tell the action where to look for the data to bind the models. [Customize model binding behavior with attributes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/model-binding)

Comment: @Nkosi Interesting quote from the link:  _"T[]: With the exception of arrays of type byte[], binding sets parameters of type T[] to Array.Empty<T>(). Arrays of type byte[] are set to null."_

Comment: Which directly explains why you are getting null.

Comment: @Nkosi yup, as you found the page, do you want o stick it on as a answer?

Comment: If I were you, I would also ask myself: *What am I gaining by using a `byte[]` instead of `int[]`?*

Comment: @CodingYoshi It's a byte array generated by MongoDB's `ObjectID` type.

Comment: @CodingYoshi In fact, the user would never type this in, it's passed via a post, redirect, get.

Comment: @BanksySan I understand a user would never pass this. I mean if you just change it to `int[]` every thing will work and was wondering why you were so keen on using `byte[]`.

Comment: @CodingYoshi Only that I noticed the _oddity_ because I originally tried `byte[]`.  Using `int[]` isn't an issue, if the `int` doesn't fit into a `byte` then I'll just return a `404`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Why can't I bind to a byte array?

As explained here [How model binding works](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/model-binding#how-model-binding-works), the following excerpt shows why you receive null.

> When a parameter is bound, model binding stops looking for values with
>   that name and it moves on to bind the next parameter. Otherwise, the
>   default model binding behavior sets parameters to their default values
>   depending on their type:
>
> `T[]`: With the exception of arrays of type `byte[]`, binding sets parameters of type `T[]` to `Array.Empty<T>()`. Arrays of type `byte[]` are set to `null`.